# how to grep to find and replace the first character in a row

Tags: r

I've got a data frame called `newdataOrder`, as follows:

**Data**

```
newdataOrder <-structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L
), X46425202 = c(184717073L, 561584L, 50107903L, 50107903L, 156680451L, 
7156823L, 38227281L, 101279027L, 222268L, 109092539L), X46624292 = c(186846060L, 
43795937L, 180611420L, 180611420L, 158620885L, 7328299L, 38404631L, 
101431772L, 38427295L, 133471230L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

        1   46425202    46624292
        1   184717073   186846060
        5   561584       43795937
        5   50107903    180611420
        5   50107903    180611420
        7   156680451   158620885
        8   7156823     7328299
        8   38227281    38404631
        8   101279027   101431772
        9   222268      38427295
        10  109092539   133471230
```

I want to insert 'per' before the first digit in the first column. To try to do this I did:

```
newdataOrder <- grep("/^","per",newdataOrder[1])
```

but alas no joy. I've tried double, and triple backslashing the caret but no joy. Can anyone help?

Comment: `paste0('per', newdataOrder[, 1])` ?

Comment: that doesnt keep it as a dataframe and gives me [1] "per1"  "per1"  "per5"  "per5"  "per5"  "per7"  "per8"  "per8"  "per8"  "per9"  "per10" "per11" "per11" "per11" "per14" "per14" "per16" "per17" "per17" "per18" "per18" "per18" "per19" without its associated columns

Comment: working on @rawr and your comment: `newdataOrder[,1] <- paste0('per', newdataOrder[, 1])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rawr is right you just need to assign that to the dataframe column you want to replace so the complete code would be

newdataOrder[,1] <- paste('per', newdataOrder[,1])

then if you call newdataOrder it this column will be prepended with the "per", but you should note that this column is now not numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [sub](http://rfunction.com/archives/2354) for replacements, because grep is for searching only:

```
newdataOrder[1] = sub("^","per",newdataOrder[1])
```

Comment: OK as an quickie extension- did I need to backslash the caret in my grep or does it recognise it as a regular expression without needing to do that?